# What is the definition of social welfare in monopoly?

Tags: microeconomics, monopoly

I'm studying problem that requires me to calculate social welfare in a monopoly setting.

But I dont know what social welfare is, and I can't find it in my book or by googling. What am I asked to compute?

Answer (score 2):

By social welfare your professor probably means total [economic surplus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_surplus) which is the sum of consumer's surplus and producer's surplus.

Comment: You can enlarge your answer by providing a mathematical definition for consumer surplus (i.e. the reservation price minus the paid price) and producer surplus (i.e. the profits).

Comment: @one_teach_wonder Profits are not the same as producers surplus (the difference is the fixed cost). But yes, a more detailed answer would be nice, if you care to make one I would be happy to upvote it.